# Boolean modifier adds verticies but doesn't remove anything

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm using the boolean modifier to remove a cylinder shape from a partial cone, as shown here
[image]

However, after applying, the partial cone is still one solid piece. When I enter edit mode, I see that there are vertices, but all the faces are still there.

[image]

How can I cut the cylinder out of the partial cone?

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: This can be caused by either mesh being [non manifold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7914/86891)

Comment: I can upload the file, but I have made some changes. I found that if I moved the objects slightly, it did cut that out. I'll try to reproduce it, and if I can, I'll upload the file.

Comment: Here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-mxA_wbO-gPJTjtvJKqVzIrSMelyZFfu/view?usp=sharing. You can see the same thing happening in the current version where I'm trying to cut six more holes along the base, and one of he cylinders isn't cutting